# 'TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK' and 'INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS' errors API transfers from adwords to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I'm using the BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google AdWords to get adwords data into my data warehouse built in google-bigquery.

For some of the transfers I get the 'TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK' and 'INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS' error. With the message "Will retry later".
After waiting a couple of weeks the errors still persists though.

I've got 10+ really large adwords accounts, so the amount of data are probably larger than for most users of adwords.

I can't find any information on how to increase any potential limit on the amount of data being transferred. Or information on the errors. Anyone who have had the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: I'd suggest opening a ticket with support or raising an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%20status:open